# How do I fix this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing an application where people ask questions, and get answers in the form of a survey. Each question has 2 options, plus a default option(s). When a person answers the question, they can choose from either the 2 options set by the asker, or the default option(s) chosen by me. For instance, if the question is Vanilla vs. Chocolate, options will be Vanilla, Chocolate, and Neither. I want to be able to tabulate the percentage of options chosen for a question, i.e., 25% say chocolate, 30% say vanilla, 45% say neither.

I'll start by showing the table structure and the query I'm running.

These are the tables involved (Note: these are not the full table structures):

```
--questions--
id
user_id
topic
description

--options--
id
text
default (bool)

--questions_options--
question_id
option_id

--answers--
id
question_id
user_id
option_id
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
options.id AS option_id, options.text, options.default, 
ROUND( 
  IFNULL( 
    (COUNT(answers.option_id) * 100) 
    / 
    (SELECT COUNT(answers.option_id) FROM answers WHERE question_id = QUESTION_ID) 
  , 0) 
, 2) AS percentage 
FROM options 
LEFT JOIN questions_options ON questions_options.option_id = options.id 
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.option_id = options.id 
WHERE questions_options.question_id = QUESTION_ID 
OR options.default = '1' 
GROUP BY options.id 
ORDER BY percentage DESC, option_id ASC
```

Where QUESTION_ID is an integer constant.

**The problem is** the query is not limiting answers to only those given for a particular question, and because the options are many to many with questions, I'm getting results like `600% for vanilla` (if multiple questions use vanilla as an option). In cases where the options are unique to ONE question, then the percentages make sense, except for the default options, which are present for all questions. I tried putting `WHERE answers.question_id = QUESTION_ID` in there, but it did not work.

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: **WHAT** database - which version ???? SQL = Structured Query Language - that's just the query language - not a product.....

Comment: I see no problem with 600% vanilla. It is delicious.

Comment: MySQL 5.1.54, for a PHP application, if that helps.

Comment: I guess 600% for vanilla is tolerable lol... but tons of questions have simple yes/no options. Answers to other questions leak into the results, so these numbers can get wild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the joins in the wrong direction - you're looking at *options* first, even though you have specifically stated you want things tabulated by *question*.  This means that you're getting results for all options, regardless of whether or not they even relate to your question...
Oh, and I'm assuming that `answer_id` is mapped to `question_id`, or you're not going to be able to get *any* meaningful results (that is - answers are not otherwise mapped to questions...)

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT b.id, b.text, b.default, (SELECT IFNULL(
                                           ROUND((COUNT(c.id) * 100) / 
                                                    (SELECT COUNT(d.id)
                                                     FROM answers as d
                                                     WHERE d.answer_id = a.question_id)
                                                 , 2)
                                               , 0)
                                 FROM answers as c
                                 WHERE c.answer_id = a.question_id
                                 AND c.option_id = a.option_id) as percentage

FROM questions_options as a
JOIN options as b
ON b.id = a.option_id
WHERE a.question_id = QUESTION_ID
ORDER BY percentage DESC, a.option_id ASC
```

Please note that I don't have a copy of MySQL to run this against, and I would normally implement with CTEs (which I have been informed are not supported for MySQL).

---

EDIT:

In light of the fact that 'default' options may not be mapped through the `questions_options` table, try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.text, a.default, IFNULL(
                                       ROUND((b.answerCount * 100) / 
                                                     (SELECT COUNT(c.id)
                                                      FROM answers as c
                                                      WHERE c.answer_id = QUESTION_ID)
                                             , 2)
                                       , 0)                                            

FROM options as a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.option_id, count(c.id) as answerCount
           FROM answers as c
           WHERE c.question_id = QUESTION_ID
           GROUP BY c.option_id) as b
ON b.option_id = a.id
```

Please note that you will still get "meaningless" '0' results for every 'default' answer that was *not* presented to survey respondents - and no way to distinguish these from any *actual* '0' results results for 'default' answers that *were* presented to respondents.  You are likely to be **far** better off placing the so called 'default' options in the `questions_options` table - as it is, you have no way to determine *all* the options that were presented to respondents (just which ones you have answers to, which is quite different); this may be a huge business-accountability issue for your company.  In addition, some 'default' options may not make sense in context - "Do you prefer your tea hot or cold", "Yes".

Comment: oh yes, sorry about that typo, answer_id should be question_id. One thing I see missing the inclusion of default options though.

Comment: I suppose a RIGHT JOIN on the options table, and the inclusion of `OR default = '1'` should work.

Comment: ... You realize if you do that, you'll get the results of all options, regardless of whether or not they relate to your question, right?  That is - "What is your favorite flavor of ice cream?" - 0% responded "Ron Weasley is my Favorite HP Character".

Comment: Oh, I see... because that would give priority to the options table. But then how would I go about getting the default options, as thats an important aspect?

Comment: It all works, except for the default options. I dont know how I would go about including options that are not explicitly mapped to a question through the questions_options table.

Comment: How many 'default' answers are there (total), and how many can be applied to a particular question - that is, if 'Yes/No' and 'Neither' are both 'default' answers, which of them can be applied to the question 'Do you prefer chocolate or vanilla'?  If the answer is 'some number greater than 1', and 'some number less than the previous', then you *must* map your default questions in the questions_options table, or you risk getting some fairly weird options when presenting questions...

Comment: default options are for the benefit of those people who do not necessarily agree with the options given.. They are set by me, and used site-wide... As of now, the only default option is 'neither', so to avoid a dichotomic debate. Although in the future, if I see fit, I may add more, something like 'who cares', for those who do not care about the topic...

Answer (score 0):

Issues that I can see:

- You `GROUP BY` `options.id` which means you are getting random values for `options.text` and `options.default`.  This may or may not change your results depending on the structure of  your data.  If there are multiple rows per `id` then it will be inaccurate or misleading data.
- You have a `WHERE` clause for your divisor but not  your dividend in the percentage calculation - this means you will never have a lower count for the dividend.  Try putting a `WHERE question_id = QUESTION_ID` to the first `COUNT` statement.

Comment: Whats wrong with grouping by options.id, that's what I want, is to group answers by the option that was chosen. Wouldn't that be equivalent to grouping by answers.option_id?

Comment: If you group by one field and select others without aggregation, you get random results from those other fields.  The point of `GROUP BY` is to combine rows.  If you only combine SOME fields, you get random rows from the other fields.  Most RDBMS will not allow you to do this.

Comment: Also, I thought the WHERE clause at the end was supposed to limit the dividend? If I added `WHERE question_id = QUESTION_ID`, then I'll get 100% for everything.